# What's the distribution of a noncentral chi squared variable plus a constant?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a random variable $X$ following the gaussian distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. 
If I define $Y := X^2$, then I know that $Y$ is has a non central chi square distribution with 1 degree of freedom :
$$
Y \sim \chi^2_1(\lambda), \ \ \lambda = \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2},
$$
right?

Now if I define a third variable
$$
Z := Y + k = X^2 + k,
$$
with $k$ a positive constant, what is the distribution of $Z$? Is it also noncentral chi square? If so, with which parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: A noncentral chi square distribution is typically described as having support on $[0,\infty)$.  Add $k$ and you get support on $[k,\infty)$ so this translated noncentral chi square distribution is not a typical noncentral chi square distribution

Comment: One could find the pdf of $Z=X^2+k$ from the pdf of $X$ to see the answer for him/herself.